# assigning a variable using a separate module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, rgb, python-module

I have been learning python for a while now, and thought it was about time to learn more about modules. Specifically, how to write them. I have been working through PyGame for a while now, and have grown annoyed with having to define each color that I use. I thought this would be a good place to start with writing a module, but I ran into an error straight away. What I want is something like this, but I don't know how to assign the tuple of rgb to the color in the main script.

Main script:

```
import rgb_color as rgb
red = rgb.red()
```

Module:

```
red():
  (255,0,0)
```

Comment: Learn to write functions first, and fix your function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should probably spend some more time with the basics, such as functions, before heading into modules.

Still, here you do not need a function, though. A "constant" will do the trick just fine. (Note that there are no *true* constants in Python, though, just don't modify the values). Just write

```
red = (255, 0, 0)
```

in your module file, or perhaps even better

```
RED = (255, 0, 0) # All caps
```

to better signal that it is supposed to be a constant value.

Then, when you import your module the constant becomes available. Perhaps it would be a good idea to also look at what `__all__` does if you ever think about doing `from rgb_color import *` even though this is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. And i will take your advice and learn more about module basics, but practice is the best way to learn. Thanks for spending your time to help! :) Also, I know I could just type red = (255, 0, 0), but I can also put in my module purple, which is harder to remember off the top of your head.

Comment: @sonicsword but you can't practice things you don't know. Guessing syntax then asking why it inevitably doesn't work is not an effective way to learn a programming language (or maintain an SO account that is permitted to ask more questions). Learn the basics first: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. Also why is purple harder to remember than red? Why can't you/do you need to remember what the colours are?

Comment: @johanl `from rgb_color import *`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Of course, I'll change it.